# ReplaceWith and alert a message in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want replace a code with other code, after click on new code get alert, but don't work alert in my code. how can fix it?

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/9Ggsn/

**Html:**

```
<select>
    <option>select 1</option>
    <option>select 2</option>
    <option>select 3</option>
</select>
<div class="dfg"><a href="#">Test</a></div>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$('select').on('change', function(){
    //alert('ook');
    $('.dfg a').replaceWith('<a href="#" class="pon">Link</a>')
});
$('.pon').on('click', 'a', function(){
    alert('ook');
});
```

Comment: You are removing an element from the DOM, re-apply its associating binding

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because in your markup `a.pon` doesn't have parent element with class of `pon`, event should be delegated from one of static parents of the element or document object.

Change:

```
$('.pon').on('click', 'a', function(){
```

To:

```
$(document).on('click', 'a.pon', function(){
```

Or:

```
$('.dfg').on('click', 'a.pon', function(){
```

Comment: I think $('.dfg') would be suitable in this case, not complete document.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$(document).on('click', '.pon', function(){
    alert('ook');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are removing an element from the DOM therefore you have to re-bind.

```
$('select').on('change', function(){
        //alert('ook');
        $('.dfg a').replaceWith('<a href="#" class="pon">Link</a>');
        BindLink();
    });

function BindLink(){
    console.log("in link");
    $('.pon').on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        alert('ook');
    });
}
```

See this fiddle [fiddle Update](http://jsfiddle.net/9Ggsn/4/)

Answer (score -1):

```
$('select').on('change', function(){
    //alert('ook');
    $('.dfg a').replaceWith('<a href="#" class="pon">Link</a>')
});
$('body').delegate('.pon','click', function(){
    alert('ook');
});
```